# How do I stop pyCharm from complaining about underscore strings?

Tags: python, pycharm, wxglade

I'm programming in pyCharm making a wxPython project (Mostly generated from wxGlade). If I have some code which specifies a string e.g.:

```
value_label = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, _("Value"))
```

It then complains about `Unresolved reference '_'`. Is there any way to ignore only this unresolved reference?

Comment: Does that code run? I use PyCharm, and an 'unsolved reference' usually warns of an upcoming `NameError` at runtime.

Comment: Yes the code runs fine. This https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/dgazGLqcZwE mentions something about it being an "internationalization feature"

Comment: is that a django get text? you can do this i think `from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _`

Comment: During initialization of the GUI I import `import gettext` and then run `gettext.install("app")` which defines the global name '_'

Comment: @Jackburridge [`gettext.install`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html#gettext.install) adds the `_` function to the built-in namespace (so you don't have to import it in every module that uses it). It seems like PyCharm doesn't know this by default.

Comment: @Bakuriu is there a way to get pycharm to ignore this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can change the settings of the *Unresolved reference* inspection:

- Open the *Settings...* menu
- Select the *Inspections* page
- Search for *Unresolved references* and click the inspection. On the bottom-right you should see a list widget titled *Ignore references*.
- Add `_` to the list.

**Warning:** this will ignore the unresolved reference `_` in **all** source files of the project. This isn't usually a problem because it's highly unlikely that you'd use that kind of name for your functions. If you ever get a `NameError` about `_` then you already know that you forgot to call `gettext.install`.

Alternatively:

- Open the offending file and place the cursor at an occurence of `_`.
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the context menu (this may depend on the shortcuts you chose or configured).
- Select *Ignore unresolved reference `module_name._`*
- Select *Fix all 'Unresolved references' problems*

---

I just checked and it's possible to limit this to only a module. If you are using `_` inside module `a` then add `a._` to the list *Ignore references* and all usages of `_` inside the `a.py` module will be ignored, while the warnings will be shown for misuses of `_` in other modules.

Answer (score 15):

Another option is to include this above the class/method/function you are writing:

```
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
```

Answer (score 2):

As the original question implies, this is a real problem for i18n'd code which ends up flagging every occurrence of a string marked with _(). My solution, which trades the hundreds of red flags for one, is to add this to the code:

```
    # Keep PyCharm happy.
    _ = _
```

The one red flag this causes is easy enough to ignore, and keeps reminding me that though I love PyCharm, it is not *perfect* :-).