# PyCharm raising Unresolved reference + expression expected for mypy ignore based on error code

Tags: pycharm, type-hinting, mypy

I am trying to [silence mypy errors based on error codes](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/error_codes.html#silencing-errors-based-on-error-codes).  This is done using something like this:

```py
from foolib import foo  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
```

I believe PyCharm is interpreting my `type: ignore[code]` comments as a type comment, and reporting `ignore` as an unresolved reference.

[image: Unresolved reference on type comment]

Also, PyCharm expects an expression within the brackets.

[image: Expression expected within type ignore comment]

`mypy` error I'm trying to suppress:

```
pylint_ignore.py:8: error: Skipping analyzing 'pylint.utils': found module but no type hints or library stubs  [import]
```

And yes, I know I can just say `type: ignore`, and not include a code, or specify to ignore this particular import in a config file.  However, I would like to specify the error codes, because I think it's a good feature.

**How can I get PyCharm not to complain about this?**

---

**Research**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23020299/11163122) to [How do I stop pyCharm from complaining about underscore strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019580/how-do-i-stop-pycharm-from-complaining-about-underscore-strings)

Helped me realize under `Preferences --> Editor --> Inspections --> Python --> Unresolved references`, I can add a fully qualified symbol name to be ignored.

I believe this is officially documented [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/resolving-references.html).

I tried adding `*.ignore.*` (since I don't want to have to build up a per-module ignore list), but this didn't work.

If this is the right approach, can you help me figure out the right syntax?

---

**Versions**

```
mypy==0.770
python==3.6.5
PyCharm PE 2020.1
```

Comment: Related issue on their bug tracker: [https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19917](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19917). No info on how to suppress the warnings though.

Comment: Thank you @Georgy, I have upvoted that issue!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently if you put a literal tab character between the `#` and `type:`, PyCharm will treat it as a regular comment. As PyCharm normally converts tab to spaces, you will have to copy it in from somewhere, but hey...

Comment: Not a bad solution.  Now PyCharm warns (not raises error) `PEP 8: E262 inline comment should start with '# '`.  I think a warning is better than an error, good thinking.  Unfortunately, my code is also part of a CI pipeline that includes `flake8`, which flags this tab character.  This is indeed a workaround, unfortunately, it will not work for me.

Comment: You can silence individual PEP 8 violation warnings in PyCharm as well as in your linter. In PyCharm, simply add E262 to inspection “PEP 8 coding style violations”. If you use flake8, you can add a “no quality assurance” comment like this: `# type: ignore[misc] # noqa: 262`, or run flake8 like this: `flake8 --ignore=E262`

Comment: I am aware of using `noqa` comments and I agree that does the trick for `flake8`.  PyCharm still complains with a weak warning, but I can look past that, or add in a `# noinspection` comment (though that'd be overkill).  I just wish PyCharm would fix the bug... pasting in `# type: ignore[import]  # noqa: E262` from an external source is a hassle.  Thanks again for pointing this workaround out @squirrel!